# Session Cookie isn't sent to the server

Tags: http, dart, session, cookies, request

I try to emulate the access to the webservice of my company using a dart file.

Here is my request where I try to send the jsessionid cookie to the server :

```
taches = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://test1.beotic.net/beop3server62/p3servicejson'),
        headers: ({
          "content-type": "application/json-rpc",
          "set-cookie": setcookie
        }),
      body: body
    );
```

The recuperate the **setcookie** variable is from the response header of a previous request that I sent to the server with an authentication token, what's inside **setcookie** look like this : *JSESSIONID=01D68460B589F3B34A9C3208FA6CEA51; Path=/beop3server62; Secure*

But it seems that the **setcookie variable is never sent** to the server as the response to this last request always contains a different **jsessionid cookie** in its headers and the body is :

> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"10","error":{"code":0,"message":"The user is
> not
> authentified","data":{"exceptionTypeName":"com.beotic.apps.p3.exception.AuthentificationException","message":"The
> user is not authentified"}}}

I'm quite lost with all this as I tried many different things and none of them seem to work.

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 0):

`Set-Cookie` is a **response** header, not a request header.

Clients should read [the `Set-Cookie` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie), use the information in it to store data in their internal cookie jars, then generate [`Cookie` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) headers from the cookie jars when making subsequent requests to the same host.